# System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache is not working in Azure environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, azure

I have deployed MVC application on Azure it was working fine during first 10 min but after 10 min it's stop working well, I have used System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache to store left menu object in Cache I debug this & came to know that Cache object is not returning any data and shows empty values cache duration was 60 min. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Doesn't ObjectCache get disposed if Azure recycles the App Pool?

Comment: ObjectCache is an abstract class, in order to get help you have to provide relevant code lines, configuration used, error messages/stack traces. As for app pool recycling - it certainly does occur on 10 min. (for Web Sites it is 20 minutes, for Web Roles - it is default for IIS, but developer can change it to whatever number they want). And even if this is the case - Caching eviction must be handled appropriately regardless of the environment.